# Storing images in MongoDB locally via script/json

Tags: node.js, json, database, mongodb, multer

I am building a project using the MEVN stack. The website is a game seller web, and when I had to store the images in the Mongo database, I realised that it was a little bit more difficult than I thought. I finally used multer to store the images but I am only able to store them using POSTMAN and its file upload functionality. My problem is the customer wants a local demo with already stored data in the database, without using any external program. I've worked with Mongo and I know it is possible to charge the DB data using a JSON file or even a JSON variable into the DB script, but I don't know if it is possible to include the image 'originalName' from a image already stored in the /uploads folder.

This is my game model:
[MongoDB game model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obkua.png)

Here is the DB object and the way the image is stored (Then I use the originalName to get it via relative paths):
[MongoDB Compass DB object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EScRa.png)

And finally here is my post method (Currently I'm using POSTMAN to populate the data and it is tedious):
[POST game method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNebP.png)

Please I need a way to store this 'image name' into my DB at the beginning of the first compilation of the project. I don't even know if I have to store the images first and then export the project with this base images to populate the database, or there is an easier way to do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi there! This does not directly solve the issue described above but since you also asked if there's an easier way - You can check out [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), it's a cloud media management service. You can use their SDK to upload your images to the cloud and get a URL in return, you can then save this URL in your database in place of filenames or paths... that won't scale anyways. This is a [sample project](https://github.com/IAMOTZ/node-react-cloudinary) using node/react/multer to explain how to go about Cloudinary upload.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the customers want a completely local solution for this Demo. I'll check it for next releases ;).